# Square elements of diagonal of lower cholesky using c++ library eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I am wondering why this will not compile using Eigen:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

int main() {

  VectorXd Q = V.llt().matrixL().diagonal().array().pow(2);
}
```

I want to take the square of the diagonal elements of the lower cholesky decomposition in one step like above but I cannot because the compiler says:

```
error: no member named 'diagonal' in 'Eigen::TriangularView<const
      Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1>'
        MatrixXd Q = V.llt().matrixL().diagonal().array().pow(2);
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mvt.dir/src/rentalmain.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mvt.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have to assign the Cholesky to another matrix and then perform the other calculations. I am wondering why this is necessary, and how I can get around it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TriangularView` does not have a `diagonal()` member (I don't know why). You can use the full `matrixLLT()` matrix (returns a ref to the underlying matrix) like so: `VectorXd Q = V.llt().matrixLLT().diagonal().array().square();`. The expression `matrixL()` just returns a `TriangularView` of the same underlying matrix that `matrixLLT()` returns.